# HBase Mapreduce Dependency Issue when using TableMapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, build.gradle, cloudera-cdh

I am using CDH5.3 and I am trying to write a mapreduce program to scan a table and do some proccessing. I have created a mapper which extends TableMapper and exception that i am getting is :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hadoop-2.5-cdh-3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:388)
```

but as you can note here it is searching for protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar in the hdfs path but actually it is present in the local path - /usr/local/hadoop-2.5-cdh-3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar , i verified . This is not happening with normal mapreduce programs . only when i am using TableMapper this error happens .

My driver code is as following :

```
   public class AppDriver  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 Configuration hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", PropertiesUtil.getZookeperHostName());
    hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientport", PropertiesUtil.getZookeperPortNum());

 Job job = Job.getInstance(hbaseConfig, "hbasemapreducejob");

    job.setJarByClass( AppDriver.class );

    // Create a scan
    Scan scan = new Scan();

    scan.setCaching(500);        // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);    // don't set to true for MR jobs
    // scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(PropertiesUtil.getHbaseStartRowkey()));
    //  scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(PropertiesUtil.getHbaseStopRowkey()));

 TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(PropertiesUtil.getHbaseTableName(),scan, ESportMapper.class, Text.class, RecordStatusVO.class, job);
    job.setReducerClass( ESportReducer.class );

    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);

    // Write the results to a file in the output directory
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath( job, new Path( args[1] ));


   boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (!b) {
        throw new IOException("error with job!");
    }

}
```

I am taking properties file as args[0] .

some more underline info :

> i am using standalone CDH 5.3 in my local system and hbase 0.98.6 . 
>   my hbase is running on top of hdfs in sudo distributed mode .

my gradle.build is as following :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application' 
 // Basic Properties
 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 targetCompatibility = '1.7'

 version = '3.0'
 mainClassName ="com.ESport.mapreduce.App.AppDriver"


 jar {
    manifest { 
     attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

 from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it :   zipTree(it) }
}

 zip64 true
}


repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
maven { url "http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-  repos/" }
}

dependencies {

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
compile 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:0.9.4'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.5'
compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.7.1'

compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.5.0-cdh5.3.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
compile('org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.6-cdh5.3.0') {

    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    exclude group: 'org.jruby'
    exclude group: 'jruby-complete'
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson'

}

compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:0.98.6-cdh5.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:0.98.6-cdh5.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:0.98.6-cdh5.3.0'

compile('com.thinkaurelius.titan:titan-core:0.5.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
compile('com.thinkaurelius.titan:titan-hbase:0.5.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.hbase'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
compile('com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-java:2.6.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}
compile 'org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.1.2'
```

}

and i am using this command to run the jar :

> hadoop jar ESportingMapReduce-3.0.jar config.properties /myoutput

Comment: also i want to add here is , this  jar is not hbase dependency jar but a hadoop jar which is present in hadoop common lib path as can be noted . hbase jars i am attaching to the build as can be noted in the build.gradle .

Comment: try adding HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hbase-env.sh

Comment: Please let me know what is there in your config.properties file

Comment: @Thanga config.properties have all configuration related properties like zookeeperhostname , portname, hbase table name , etc .

Comment: @mbaxi no help . same as before .

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to setup in hbase in pseudo distributed mode, most probable reason for this adding hadoop home to `$PATH`.
By just removing hadoop home from `$PATH` you can start hbase in pseudo distributed mode.
Some people by default add hadoop home in `.bashrc`.
If you are added it in .bashrc remove hadoop home from it.

Comment: It worked to me, but I don't understand. Why is it necessary remove the hadoop home from path?